# Send data from file to local UDP port

Tags: networking, port, udp, playback

I've got an application, A, that listens on a user-defined UDP port for a specific message that normally comes from another application, B. Application B has a tool that allows recording these messages into a data file. I'd like to be able to take the messages from this data file, parse them, and then send them to the UDP port that application A is listening on.

Are there any tools out there that can do something like this? And failing that, could you make a recommendation on how to roll this myself via script, etc.?

The important part would be sending the data to a local UDP port, I imagine I'll have to parse it myself into whatever form the tool expects.

A portable solution is preferred, but XP support is required.

Comment: from StackOverflow: [Send and Receive data via UDP in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148666/send-and-receive-data-via-udp-in-powershell)

Comment: @techie007 Fantastic! I'm embarrassed I didn't find this on my own >_<